# Status: 302 Found Location:

Tags: perl, cgi

Hello i want to redirect at another location after delete data from database. But it shows me the following error:Status: 302 Found Location:

```
my $q= new CGI;
print $q->header ('Text/html');

print $q-> start_html(
   -title   => "",

);
my $db = "peroples";
my $user = "root"; 
my $pass = "";
my $host="127.0.0.1";
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host", $user, $pass);
my $action_delete = $q->param('delete');
my $action_update = $q->param('update');


if($action_delete + 0 > 0) {
        my $row_id = $action_delete + 0;
        my $sqlQuery  = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM peoples WHERE ID = $row_id");
        $sqlQuery->execute;    
 print $q->redirect(-uri => 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/peoples.pl',);
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the redirect header before you start the HTML. First `print $q->redirect`, then afterwards any message body content such as `$q->start_html`.

Learn what a [HTTP message](http://enwp.org/HTTP_body_data#HTTP_message) looks like, and how its header and body parts work. If you put the redirect into the body, it cannot work.

Comment: How is the redirect header?

Comment: This line: print $q->redirect(-uri => 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/ova/laura/peoples.pl',)

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? You wrote a script that deletes something from a database and that redirects to itself.